# window.Event vs window.event

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, events, dom-events

For some reason when fired through C# code by using the `IHTMLElement2.focus()` method call, an `onfocus` event will not set `window.event` (which will become null), instead some other object `window.Event` will get set with the event information. Is there a reason for this? I am using `ShDocVw` interface for InternetExplorer and this is the first time I have seen this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a typical microsoft bug.  They often have a problem with case sensitivity since it has been onverlooked as a distinction since day one of the OS.

I would suggest maybe looking into this kb article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa703985(v=vs.85).aspx  specifically the tabindex hooha which sounds like a joke, but what else would you expect.

Then I would suggest trying the 4th variant form of IHTMLElement particularly the onfocusin event as an alternative to onfocus.

But ultimately since you control the environment via the shdocvw object - I'd just map the window.Event object to the window.event object in your onfocus handler - one line of code never hurt no one - except for when that one line of code hurts someone with a stack overflow, buffer overrun or Out of Memory exception of course :D

Comment: Yeah, we would have to change var evt = e || window.event; to var evt = e || window.event || window.Event; I find that pretty dumb, I'll try the onfocusin instead. Thanks